# "aus ernsten Augen anblicken"-meaning

Tags: meaning-in-context

Here is a sentence:

> Sie blickte ihn nur aus ernsten Augen an.

My question is what would be the most idiomatic translation of "aus ernsten Augen"? Couldn't find a matching use-case for the "aus" preposition. DeepL suggests

> She only looked at him from serious eyes.

Sounds kind of clumsily put to me.

Comment: How about "She gave him a serious look"? Not everything can be literally translated word by word.

Comment: You are asking for a better English expression.

Comment: The English translation should be selected by an English native speaker, but from my understanding of the German phrase, I note that it is similar to "she just gave him a pensive look / melancholic look" ...?

Comment: What I see here is actually NOT what I imagine from the German phrase: https://fineartamerica.com/featured/an-earnest-look-peter-gartner.html?product=art-print

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I’m not a native English speaker (but a German), so you won’t get a good idiomatic translation from me, but I think I can help you get the gist of the whole sentence so that you can write your own translation.

There are, in my opinion, 3 peculiarities that give the phrase a deeper meaning:

1. "nur": Yes, the translation would be "only" or maybe "just". But the purpose of that word in this sentence is, to make it clear that "she" *does nothing* but look. At this moment she is only busy looking at him. Fully focused, nothing else matters.
2. "aus": As already written in another answer, one usually says someone looks "*mit* ihren Augen". The word "aus" (from) creates/reinforces the impression that she is *actively* looking instead of being a passive observer. Her gaze hits him like a ray of light.
3. "ernste Auge ": Yes, this is "serious eyes". But I’m not sure, if this formulation is quite accurate or at least if it is strong enough. Serious eyes in this case are not just sad or angry or "not happy" or anything, but they create an impression of ultimate seriousness that  leaves no room for maneuver.

Of course not completely objectively, but that’s how I feel it. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

The phrasing is slightly unusual in German. Normally you would say:

> Sie blickte ihn nur **mit** ernsten Augen an.

And generally, you do looking *mit* your eyes, not *aus* your eyes in German most of the time; however, *aus* may be rare, but it is easily understandable, and does not seem wrong to German speakers (plus it is plenty attested throughout the ages).

*Mit ernsten Augen* (and similar phrases, like *mit traurigen, fröhlichen, neugierigen Augen* etc.) is a very common expression, and as such is a little “worn,” i.e., people read over it, think „Aha, ernste Stimmung“, and do not really have a picture of earnest eyes before their inner eye. It is a nice writer's trick to make all-too commonplace metaphors come to life again by using a slightly unusual phrasing. (A simple example I recall from [Wolf Schneider](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wolf_Schneider) was to write „Wellen, hoch wie Häuser“ instead of the stock phrase „haushohe Wellen“, which technically means the same thing.) This may be the intention of the author here.

In any event, you want to know what would be the “most idiomatic translation” of a sentence that, most likely intentionally, *avoids* the most idiomatic phrasing in German. That is probably really a question for [English Language SE](https://english.stackexchange.com/), but you may want to use a slightly unusual phrasing in English too, e.g. “she gave him a look from serious eyes” or something similar.